# How to fix Visual Studio 2019 from only rebuilding one file in my C++ project when run

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, visual-studio-debugging

When I run my project in C++, Visual Studio only rebuilds the file with the main method in it but when I update code in the other file, no changes occur. However, when I manually rebuild the program in Visual Studio, all the files get rebuilt. To attempt to fix this, I tried to delete the hidden .vs extension in the project but to no avail. I also tried to reboot my system and program but nothing seems to work. I also tried to start a new project but this problem still continues.

For example this is my code for my first file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Source.cpp"

int main()
{
    TESTING tst = TESTING();
}
```

Then this is my code for the second file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct TESTING{

    TESTING() {
        cout << "test" << endl;
    }
};
```

The code prints test in this situation.

But if I change the cout << "test" << endl to something else, it will continue printing test when I rerun it until I manually rebuild the project.

Comment: I'd guess the second file is not part of your project given that you are using `include` and don't have linker errors. In short, don't do that. Add it to the project so Visual Studio can understand it is a dependency.

Comment: The .cpp file exists within the Source Files folder in Visual Studio in the solution. Does that not count as being part of the project? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Nope still haven't gotten visual studio to work.

Comment: This is an issue on VS IDE and the team is investigating the problem. And you can follow the dc link  I provided to track it.

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix Visual Studio 2019 from only rebuilding one file in my C++
>   project when run

**Actually**, I get the same error in my side as you said. When I just make some changes to `source.cpp` file(chang `test` to any other else or define some variables then change it ), the new changes will not apply although it build the new changes into the output file.

**Besides**, when I debug this project, I face a warning like this:

[image]

When l click yes which means it will use the newest changed file, however when l set a breakpoint and watch the variable, it uses the previous value rather than the new value. This is really strange.

[image]

When I do some changes and then debug it(run **build**), it already build again to apply new changes and I am curious why this doesn't show new values and  **rebuild** does.

**Therefore**, it is an issue in VS C++ projects. And [this similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/990745/error-msg-current-source-code-is-different.html) has already reflect this issue. And the team are investigating this issue.

**To** help you and raise more attention, **I have reported this issue to DC Forum.** You can see [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1011738/when-build-c-project-to-apply-the-new-changes-duri.html). You can vote this issue and add any comment if I do not adequately describe this problem. Anyone who is interested in this issue will vote it so that it will arouse Microsoft's attention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your files which are not compiled are referenced in the `project.vcxproj` file (they are probably not present).
It's exactly like dependencies in a Makefile; if the dependency is not written, the build won't compile files after their update.

More specifically they should be mentionned this way:

```
<ClCompile Include="mysource1.cpp" />
<ClCompile Include="mysource2.cpp" />
<ClInclude Include="mysource1.h" />
<ClInclude Include="mysource2.h" />
```

So, it's not a fix in VS, but in your configuration.